# How to show error message when the values was not in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

**I have fetch(placing in inputboxes) the customer name and Dob from database through Customer phone . I am done the work but if I put the wrong customer number(there is no number in database) there will be show a alert box...that didn't know to me for how to do that...Can you please anyone solve my code...**

```
<input type="text" class="search">phone

 <input type="text" id="cname">name
<input type="text" id="cdob">date of birth
```

```
This is the script tag
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search').keyup(function() {
    var mobile_no = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
             url: "get_customer_info.php",
             method: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
              data:{
                search  : mobile_no
                },
                  success:function(data){
                    $.each(data,function(id, val){
                    $("#cname").val(val.cname);
                    $("#cdob").val(val.cdob);
                    });
                    }
          });
      });
});
</script>
```

```
and this is query page

<?php
include("config.php");

  $mobile=$_POST['search'];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM `cm` WHERE cphone ='$mobile'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql,true);
  if($result===true)
  {
  $mainarray=array();
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
  {
       $row['cm_id'];
       $row['cname'];
       $row['cdob'];
         array_push($mainarray, $row);
    } 
  echo json_encode($mainarray);
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'There is no data';

  }
  ?>
```

Comment: $('.search').keyup  will be very annoying with alertbox to end users, it will alert on each key entered. Instead try to have a submit button

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: sir its just college project so nothing worry about that issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front end file:

```
<input type="text" class="search">phone
<input type="text" id="cname">name
<input type="text" id="cdob">date of birth
```

Your Script file:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.search').keyup(function() {
    var mobile_no = $(this).val();
    if(mobile_no.length >= 10 ){
    $.ajax({
             url: "get_customer_info.php",
             method: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
              data:{

                search  : mobile_no
                },
                  success:function(responce){
                    if($.trim(responce)){
                    $.each(responce,function(id, val){
                    $("#cname").val(val.cname);
                    $("#cdob").val(val.cdob);
                    });
                    } else{
                        alert("no data");
                    }
                    }
          });
          }
      });
});
</script>
```

This is your get_customer_info.php file

```
    <?php
        include("config.php");

        $mobile=$_POST['search'];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM `cm` WHERE cphone ='$mobile'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql,true);
  if($result==true)
  {
  $mainarray=array();
  while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
  {
       $row['cm_id'];
       $row['cname'];
       $row['cdob'];
         array_push($mainarray, $row);
    } 
  echo json_encode($mainarray);
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'There is no data';

  } 
        ?>
```

Comment: what difficulties are you facing ..? please brief about that.!

Comment: sir can I send my entire code..?That is just 3 pages

Comment: if($result===true && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) check this condition in your mysql result condition. hope your problem will be solve.

Comment: sir can you send me a message i arsameeras7@gmail.com...i can explain clearly on that side...its my college project sir...hope you message me

Comment: @Ameer Please check now and I have tested with my end. it's working fine.